# How to build a Slack Bot to reminder dinner everyday at a specific hour?

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api

I am trying to build a `Slack Bot` to remind everyone at the `general` channel to place their dinner everyday at `07:00pm`

this is what I am been doing, but the message is shown the very second bot is running. Can you help me to schedule this bot?

``

```
const SlackBot = require('slackbots');
const axios = require('axios');

const bot = new SlackBot({
    token: 'xoxb-806332471443-820014975046-AxwmxL8n5W2iwD6surHy7aWV',
    name: 'dinnerbot'
});

//start handlers
bot.on('start', () => { 
    const params = {
        icon_emoji: ':taco:'
    }

    bot.postMessageToChannel('general', 'Hi! it is time to Order your dinner!', params); //I need to trigger this message everyday at 07:00pm
});

//error handler
bot.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

``

Comment: What you need is a reminder: https://api.slack.com/methods/reminders.add

Comment: @MojoAllmighty do you have an example on how to use this method/

Comment: You could also use a scheduled message: [`chat.sheduledMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.scheduleMessage)